# Incorrect time displaying in ArcGIS API for JavaScript popup template?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, time, date

I'm creating a web map that is updated a few times a day showing voltage readings from meters on our distribution network.

This layer has a field called ReadTime, and the data type is Date.

The date is formatted as: `0/00/0000 00:00:00 AM`

So, I'm using the shortDateLongTime format as shown [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_popuptemplate.html).

However, when I click on a meter the date comes in fine, but the time is wrong. For example, a value for one of the meters in the attribute table from ArcMap is `6/17/2015 8:00:14 AM`, but in the web map it's displaying as `6/17/2015, 1:00:14 AM`.

I'm assuming I'm missing a setting somewhere, but I haven't been able to find out where.

```
var popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
        title: "{VoltageReadings_LOCATION}",
        fieldInfos: [{
            fieldName: "VoltageReadings_READ_TIME",
            visible: true,
            label: "Read Time",
            format: {
                dateFormat: 'shortDateLongTime'
            }
        }],
        showAttachments: true
    });
```

---

Update to show what worked:

```
var popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
        title: "{VoltageReadings_LOCATION}",
        fieldInfos: [{
            fieldName: "VoltageReadings_READ_TIME",
            visible: true,
            label: "Read Time",
            format: {
                dateFormat: 'shortDateLongTime'
            }
        }],
        showAttachments: true
    }, {
        utcOffset: 0
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your time wasn't stored in UTC and is getting converted improperly.

The PopupTemplate [constructor](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popuptemplate-amd.html#popuptemplate1) has an option to set the UTC offset. Take a look at [this discussion](https://geonet.esri.com/message/429903#429903) on the ArcGIS forum for a example on how to use it.